# Using <Polygon> in react-google-maps

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import shuffle from 'shuffle-array';
import { Polygon } from "react-google-maps";

export default class MapsItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const coords = [
    { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
    { lat: 1, lng: 1 },
    { lat: 2, lng: 2 }
  ];
    const api_key="myapikeyhere"
    return (

      <div className="col-sm-12"><Polygon key={api_key} path={cords}> </Polygon> </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I have the following code; where I'm trying to draw the polygon for the map. Issue is it throws me the error called :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
```

Whenever I try an import Polygon or any component related to react-google-maps.

Am I using it right? Also how would I pass my API_KEY. I was assuming just passing the key prop to the Polygon. Not sure.

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "djreact",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "radium": "^0.16.6",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "shuffle-array": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to show your package.json

Comment: Added it on the main thread.

Comment: Have you had any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Update React, copy and paste the below, then run `npm install` or you could run `npm update`

```
{
  "name": "djreact",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.6.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.13",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "0.0.93",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "sass-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^5.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.5.1",
    "radium": "^0.16.6",
    "react-cookie": "^0.4.5",
    "react-dom": "16.3.1",
    "react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0"
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^1.0.3",
    "shuffle-array": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: WebpackError: 
        ModuleNotFoundError in 
        Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'react/lib/ReactMount' in 
        
I get that error

Comment: What are you using to make this project? are you using create-react-app?

Comment: Hey! Will give it a shot asap. I'm not using create-react-app but instead I'm using react within my Django app using webpack

Comment: Try and use create-react-app, since they handle all of this stuff for you https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/create-react-app-and-django/624/